# How to compile ".s" assembly file in Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, assembly, codeblocks, openframeworks, gcc4.9

How to compile ".s" assembly file in Code::Blocks??

I have a ".s" file, written in AT&T assembly, which is a function.

I have other code in C++.

How can I get the project compiled in Code::Blocks??

Thanks in advance.

**Env**: I'm using Code::Blocks 13.12 on Ubuntu 14.04, gcc-4.9, and **openFrameworks**

Comment: The `g++` frontend (or `gcc` for C programmers) handles assembly files with either `.S` or `.s` suffix. Have you tried to just add it to your project?

Comment: Yes, it showed up as "ASM Sources" but it is not linked into it. `undefined reference`. However if I extract the link command and mannually add the `.o` file to it. They linked greatly.

Comment: So it at least creates an object file? It's just not included in the linking? Might be a bug in the IDE.

Comment: no, no, it did not generate the object file. I generated mannually. Sorry for the vague explain which made you misunderstood.

Comment: In that case I would guess that it's CodeBlocks that can't handle assembly files, and I would still consider it a bug in the IDE. You might want to search a little more about the subject of CodeBlocks and assembly files, and in the worst case report it to the developers of CodeBlocks as a bug.

Comment: @Adam This isn't a problem in the C::B IDE. `.s` files can simply be add to a project, they appear under virtual folder **ASM Sources** and get compiled and linked without further intervention, unless something *prevents* it.

Comment: @MikeKinghan Maybe I should add to **Env** that I'm using `openFrameworks`. I cannot compile might because of that.

Comment: @MikeKinghan do you know about codeblocks configurations? Would you please help me check the openFrameworks C::B config? Thx.

Comment: @Adam I know about C::B but nothing about openFrameworks and regrettably I don't have time to dig into it. If it requires or injects some specialized configuration of C::B projects that use it, that could well be where the problem lies, 'cos it isn't inherent in C::B. To see what is really going on when C::B builds your project, look at the output under the **Build log** tab, not the
**Build messages** tab.

Comment: @MikeKinghan Thx anyway. I don't see the `.s` file compiled or linked in `Build log`.

Comment: @Adam An afterthought. Having added `foo.s` (whatever) to the project under **ASM Sources**, right-click ` foo.s` and from the menu navigate **Properties** -> **Build**. By default all the boxes **Compile file**, **Link file**, **Belongs in targets {Debug|Release}** should all be checked. Are they?

Comment: @MikeKinghan Yes, they are checked, but don't appear in C::B Build log.

Comment: Maybe in your case you need to provide a custom Makefile.

Comment: IIRC, you can set C::B to use a makefile for the build process. If you know how or are willing to invest the time to learn, you could write a makefile for the build and configure C::B to use it instead. And IMO, makefile writing is a useful skill for anyone writing compiled code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many thanks to **arturo** as he solved my problem in openFrameworks Forum, answer link:

http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/how-to-add-assembly-file-into-codeblocks/15942

OpenFrameworks use `.S` the capital S extension for assembly file under Linux.